# 正規表現で、2桁を表す書き方について

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

少し強引な書き方になりましたが、"正規表現"で分からない箇所がありますので、
よろしくお願いします。

下記のコードは、平成以降の元号が"元年",もしくは"１桁"の場合は、レッドを表示し、
元号が"２桁"の場合は、グリーンを表示，その他の場合は、ブルーを表示させようと
したものです。
現在は"平成30年"なので、グリーンで表示するかと思っていたら、ブルーで表示されます。
書き方が間違っているのでしょうか。chromeのデベロッパーツールでも、エラーは
でませんが、どのように書けば、グリーンに表示させられるでしょうか。

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
 <!--
var now=new Date();
var Gengou = now.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year:"numeric" })
    .replace(/(^|[^\d])1(?=$|[^\d])/, '$1元').replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");

if((Gengou == "元年")&&(Gengou == [2-9])){//元号が"元年",もしくは"１桁"の場合は、レッドを表示。
  document.write("<p>");
  document.write("<span style='color:red'>");
  document.write(Gengou);
  document.write("</span>");
  document.write("</p>");
}
else if(Gengou == [1-9][0-9]){//元号が"２桁"の場合は、グリーンを表示。
  document.write("<p>");
  document.write("<span style='color:green'>");
  document.write(Gengou);
  document.write("</span>");
  document.write("</p>");
}
else{//その他の場合は、ブルーを表示。
  document.write("<p>");
  document.write("<span style='color:blue'>");
  document.write(Gengou);
  document.write("</span>");
  document.write("</p>");
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: 正規表現の場合には match メソッドを使うと良いかと。[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ショートアンサー

`metropolis` さんのご指摘の通り `String.prototype.match()` を使用する場合は、
`Gengou == [2-9]` を `Gengou.match(/平成[1-9]年/)`
`Gengou == [1-9][0-9]` を `Gengou.match(/平成[1-9][0-9]年/)` に修正してみてください。

（古い版で `=~` という記述を使った答えを書いてしまっていましたが、
　対象のプログラミング言語を勘違いしていました。ごめんなさい。）

---

ロングアンサー

正規表現を意図した記述と思いますが、実際には `[2-9]` は `[-7]` （要素として `-7` を含む配列）となり、
`[1-9][0-9]` は `[-8][-9]` （要素として `-8` を含む配列の -9 番目の要素。つまり `undefined` ）として解釈されてしまいます。
（JavaScript の「配列」についてご存知なければ下記を参照ください。
　https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array ）

よって if, else if 文の条件式はそれぞれ `'平成30年' == [-7]`
`'平成30年' == undefined` となり、どちらにもマッチせず、
else 節が実行されブルーが表示されます。

`/(^|[^\d])1(?=$|[^\d])/` の箇所でもわかりますが、
JavaScript において正規表現リテラルは `/.../` の書式で記述する必要があります。
詳しくは https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions 等をご確認ください。

---

また問題のコードですと、平成元年の場合 `Gengou` 変数も `'平成元年'` となりますので
`Gengou == "元年"` も `Gengou == "平成元年"` とするのが正確です。

ついでに `条件A && 条件B` は「条件A **かつ** 条件B が満たされた場合」の意なので、
「"元年", **もしくは** "1桁"の場合」としたい場合、 `条件A || 条件B` とする必要があります。

つまり `(Gengou == "元年")&&(Gengou == [2-9])` 箇所は
`(Gengou == "平成元年")||(Gengou.match(/平成[1-9]年/))` とすれば、
意図した通りの挙動になるはずです。

以上、ご確認ください。

Comment: 回答をありがとうございました。質問に書いていませんでしたが、平成だけでなくて、次期以降の元号にも適用させたいのです。すみませんでした。条件A && 条件B は、変だなと思っていたのですが、エラーが出たので”&&”に換えたところ、エラーが消えたのです。ここでの[2-７]の”-”は、マイナスと解釈していたのですか。勉強になります。

Comment: 次期以降の年号についてですが、例えば `Gengou` 変数から「元号」の部分をカットした上で比較する案を記述します。
つまり「{元号}元年」「{元号}n年」から「元年」「n年」を抜き取るので、if 文の直前で `Gengou = Gengou.match(/元年|\d+年/)[0];` とすれば、
`Gengou` 変数が `'元年'` または `'n年'` になります。ただ、元号が除去されるので、その後の if, else if 文の条件が多少変化します。
それぞれ `(Gengou == "元年") || (Gengou.match(/[2-9]年/))` と `Gengou.match(/[1-9][0-9]年/)` に変更する必要があるでしょう。
https://repl.it/@CharlieRoot/SilkyDirtyQuadrant
（ただ、実際に年号の更新前後で各々のウェブブラウザがどのような挙動を示すかは不定です。）

Comment: 解決しました。詰めが足りませんでした。簡単に考えていましたが、複雑ですね。

Comment: 変数のGengouの他に、もう一つ変数の”Gengou2”を作って”document.write(Gengou2);”とすれば、元号も表示されますね。

Comment: `document.write(Gengou);` の箇所を見落としておりました。
ご指摘の通り、`Gengou = ...` の前に `var Gengou2 = Gengou;` としておけば `document.write(Gengou2);` で元号を含め、表示可能です。
あるいは `var Gengou2 = Gengou.match(/元年|\d+年/)[0];` として if, else if 文の条件内では `Gengou2` を比較対象にしたほうが幾分スマートかも知れません。お気に召すまま。
https://repl.it/@CharlieRoot/FuchsiaDirectThing

Comment: こちらの方が2度書きしなくていいです。無事解決しました。